# How to create a DataFrame from a text file in PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, text, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I want to convert a txt file into a Dataframe in Pyspark. I am trying to make the tidy data in pyspark. Any help? Thanks

I´ve already tried to convert it as an RDD and then into datafram, but it is not working for me, so I decided to convert it once into a dataframe from a txt file

I was trying with this but it has not worked yet.

```
 # read input text file to RDD
  lines = sc.textFile("/home/h110-3/workspace/spark/weather01.txt")

  # collect the RDD to a list
  llist = lines.collect()

  # print the list
  for line in llist:
    print(line)
```

I have not being able to convert it into a Dataframe. Help please

Comment: Your code looks good, lines is the DataFrame. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi! No, haven't get any errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can via the `text` reader ... example here:

```
! cat sample.txt
hello there
loading line by line
via apache spark
text df api
```

```py
print(spark.version)
df = spark.read.text("sample.txt")
df.printSchema()
df.show()
df.selectExpr("split(value, ' ') as rows").show(3, False)

2.4.3
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|         hello there|
|loading line by line|
|    via apache spark|
|         text df api|
+--------------------+
+-------------------------+
|rows                     |
+-------------------------+
|[hello, there]           |
|[loading, line, by, line]|
|[via, apache, spark]     |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: @DanielCruz since this solved your problem please mark as correct answer so the question can be closed and considered complete